# How to do delayed zone reload in Tapestry?

Tags: java, ajax, reload, tapestry, zone

Is there a way to do a delayed zone reload in Tapestry.

I have a not-so-quick operation I perform when I submit a form.
The results are visible after a few seconds (usually 2 or 3).

Is there a way to do a delayed zone reload, which would show some indicator that the zone will reload in x seconds and then perform the actual reload?

Comment: Any way If you make your method blocking the zone will not update untill the Java method is done and return.

Comment: I'm not working in a single-client, single-thread environment, so the only actual and reliable way to know if the content has been update is by querying remote source. However, I may assume (a strong assumption) that the operation will be recorded in 2-3 seconds.

Comment: then you should use periodic zone updater.. So if your update is not ready at 1st second, it will try again in another seocond

Comment: Like this? http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/periodicupdatemixin

Comment: Thats what i used. It works !

Comment: Thx, post that as your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the zone update requests are blocked at Java side. But as you say your application does not work in a single threaded way you can use PeriodicZoneUpdater. Where your client is polling for updates

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the zone with a throbber (or some text) while you wait

- http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/loadingspinner
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/adding-ajax-throbbers-zone

Or you can get some inspiration from the ProgressLink component which keeps polling a serverside task for it's percentage complete until it hits 100%

- http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/progresslinkdemo